# Find images but only jpeg

Tags: php

I am using the following to parse an html page and return the images:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('img') as $e){ 

    $image = $e->src;

            }
```

Ideally though I only want to show files with .jpg extension - I know I can probably use preg_match but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: check "Attribute Filters" tab in this link - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find

[attribute$=value]  Matches elements that have the specified attribute and it ends with a certain value.

Comment: I think for **just** checking extension of files preg_match is more efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### NOTE: Just because a file has a JPEG-like extension does *not* mean that the content of the referenced file is actually JPEG data!

---

[`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) is the native PHP function you are looking for. Yes you can manipulate the string however you want, but if you are looking for the "right" way to do it then here it is:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);

// file extensions we are looking for
$allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'jpe'];

foreach($html->find('img') as $el){ 
    // file extensions are usually treated as case insensitive, but the
    // implied comparison operator used with in_array() is case sensitive
    // so normalise the data to lower-case.
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($el->src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if (in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions)) {
        // File has a JPEG-like file extension
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine. This would work for your case

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.yahoo.com/');
// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
{
    $img = strtolower($element->src);
    if(pathinfo($img,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "jpg")
        echo $element->src . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: This should be the green checked answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
$split = explode(".", $image);
$extention = $split[count($split)-1];
```